# How to handle "PayloadTooLargeError" with a response or a custom error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

im trying to put a payload limit of 1kb using :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({
 limit: "1kb" ,
 strict:true
       }));
```

its working perfectly as it suppose to work , but the only problem is i get an **error** of

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
at readStream (E:\Work\FIGHTME\V1.0\api\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:155:17)
at getRawBody (E:\Work\FIGHTME\V1.0\api\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:108:12)
at read (E:\Work\FIGHTME\V1.0\api\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:77:3)
at jsonParser (E:\Work\FIGHTME\V1.0\api\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:135:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Work\FIGHTME\V1.0\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (E:\Work\FIGHTME\V1.0\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at E:\Work\FIGHTME\V1.0\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (E:\Work\FIGHTME\V1.0\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (E:\Work\FIGHTME\V1.0\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (E:\Work\FIGHTME\V1.0\api\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
```

> ***is there any way to handle this error through callback or anything so i show a custom error or send a custom response ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried like this

```
app.use(express.json({limit: '1kb'}));
```

Parsing request body as middleware is available in Express v4.16.0 onwards.

**EDIT**

If you want to customise your error message, then you need to define your error-handler middle-ware to do that. Something like this:

```
// Not tested code.
// Usually added as last middleware
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    if(err instanceof PayloadTooLargeError){
        //res.status(<your status code>).send(<your response>);
        res.status(400).send("Customized Response");
    }
    else{
        next(err);
    }
})
```

Comment: Hello Sir , thank's for the reply , my limitter is working fine , im just curious about if im able to custom my error message and send a customized response

Comment: note: HTTP status code should be [*413*](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/413) instead of *400*