# How to handle "PayloadTooLargeError" error and send custom response?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I'm using Google Cloud Functions with `express`.

I want to handle `PayloadTooLargeError` error and send a custom error message when clients sends very large data to functions (I'm using v1 functions with 10MB limit).

I've already tryed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70307866/9894625) method but it doesn't seems to work as there's no log on my console.

Here's my code at this moment:

```
const app = express()
app.use(errorHandler)

function errorHandler(
  err: any,
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) {
  // this log is not beeing printed
  console.error('there was an error:', err)
  return next(err)
}

// this is just a simple route to test
app.post( '/test', async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
) => {
  return res.end()
} )

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest( app )
```

I suppose this error happens before `express` functions are called. I've tryed exporting the function without it and got the same error.

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using [structure logs for Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#writing_structured_logs)?

Comment: I've readed but I don't understand how can I use it to handle my error as it the error happens before express app is started

Comment: You could try using the `try...catch` statement in executing your error message. You may refer to this [sample](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Developer-Tools/Error-handling-in-Cloud-functions-Cloud-Logging/m-p/617470/highlight/true#M1242) for your reference.

Comment: @RobertG nope, this don't work, it seems the function is not even called when `PayloadTooLargeError` error happens